# Kids'/Young Adult Book - TV set that shows tomorrow's news

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, childrens-novel

Trying to remember the title of a popular kids'/young adult book from the '70s - it had a Motorola television set that showed tomorrow's news. Kind of like shows like "Early Edition," where the guy gets tomorrow's newspaper each day.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [A Billion for Boris](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/808095.A_Billion_for_Boris) by Mary Rodgers?

> When Ape Face fixes a broken-down television set Boris sold to him, something unusual happens. Instead of regularly scheduled programs, this TV shows the future -- one day in advance! They get tomorrow's shows, tomorrow's movies, and tomorrow's news. Annabel thinks they should use their new TV with ESP to help people, but Boris has plans of his own ...

One of the reviews on Goodreads mentions a motorola TV.

> "*Worth reading just for the passing references to The Partridge Family and Motorola tvs.*"